# How to remove default padding and margines in Bootstrap in Angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass

like in title.
My bootstrap implements default padding and margin. I want to use something like this in app.component.scss for whole my children components:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

becouse I have to add `m-0 p-0`

```
<div class="header container-fluid p-0">
    <div class="headerShadow row align-items-center m-0">
        <h1 class="col text-center text-capitalize m-0 p-0" style="color:white">
            Welcome to the amazing book shop
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added footer and He has 16px padding:
[image]